# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Ds\Map' not found PHP

Tags: php

I have the following problem in PHP. In advance forgive me for my poor English.

I want to use the class Map in **PHP**, so I have installed the package `php-ds/php-ds` via composer. It installed perfectly, but when I use the class map, it produces an error.

**SPECS**
PHP 7.4.0

**CODE**

```
<?php

$map = new \Ds\Map(["a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3]);

var_dump($map->get("a"));      
var_dump($map->get("d", 10));   
?>
```

**ERROR**
[image]

**PROYECT STRUCTURE**
[image]

Comment: You are not including the composer autoload file in your ds.php file.

Comment: thanks for answering. @shelly could explain me how to include that?. since I have already include in `autoload_psr4` 
**View screen shot**  
 [screen shot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W3YMkbPziOQ7QNOqg4gVEAdw_YWqt_xu/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: require_once("vendor/autoload.php"); in your ds.php. You may need to change the path.

Comment: Thanks @shelly this work, but do you know why the psr4 path does not work?

Comment: Im not really familiar with psr4 in a php 4. But everything you are doing in your autoload_psr4.php can also be done in the composer.json file. Checkout the composer file of laravel: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/composer.json

Comment: You may want to accept by answer, so others know the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He forgot to include the autoload file:

```php
require_once("vendor/autoload.php");
```